# What are bilinear and quadratic forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can someone explain to me what bilinear and quadratic forms are? Please, don't give me the definitions. Instead can you give me the intuitive understanding of the concepts (meaning)?

Comment: They're generalizations of the dot product and the (square of the) Euclidean metric respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear form is a multivariate homogeneous polynomial of the first degree.

E.g.

$$f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz.$$

The locus of $f(x,y,z)=0$ is a plane through the origin.

---

A quadratic form is a multivariate homogeneous polynomial of the second degree.

E.g.

$$f(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2dxy+2eyz+2fzx.$$

The equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ represents a degenerate quadric (of the cone type) with its center at the origin. If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, so is $(\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z)$.

---

A bilinear form is a function defined on the components of two vectors, in such a way that if you consider one of the vectors as a constant, you see a linear form.

E.g.
$$f((x,y),(u,v))=axu+bxv+cyu+dyv=(au+bv)x+(cu+dv)y=(ax+cy)u+(bx+dy)v.$$

A bilinear form is perforce a quadratic form. You can generalize to trilinear and higher.